# How to release shelf on the drawer unit?

Tags: repair

I have a Bailey Unicorn Cadiz 2014. The shelf on the drawer unit won’t pull out. It gets stuck 1/3 of the way out. Any ideas as to release the shelf?

Comment: Check that nothing in the drawer is sticking up and stopping it opening.

Comment: Is this a slide-out shelf that doesn't slide or are you trying to remove the shelf?  Maybe a picture of the shelf in the unit.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [discussion](https://www.caravanclub.co.uk/club-together/discussions/information-technical-tips-advice/caravans/help-required-to-remove-a-drawer-in-a-bailey-cadiz/) there are clips on the side you press in.